# GIT: remove from 2nd to 5th commits in the remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, commit, branching-and-merging, git-commit

I'd like to fully remove several commits in the remote branch.

Reason: The branch with the only important (and the most recent) commit supposed to be **forked from** and **merged into** another branch.

Once I change the branch to a proper branch (via browser) I see several more commits that are not in that proper branch yet. I don't need them.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~5
```

and by manually applying and commiting my recent changes didn't get the result. There are even more commits now.

So, what was a proper and clear algorythm?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean executing `git reset --hard HEAD~5` and manually applying changes will get more commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh... I didn't quite understand what you want. If what you want to do is "remove" a couple of revisions from the history of a branch (either local or remote), what you have to do is this:

- Get the (sha1) IDs for both revisions you want to get rid of
- Checkout the revision *before* the oldest of the couple
- Cherry-pick revisions from the oldest to one revision before the newest of the couple (that will discard the oldest so it won't be applied)
- Cherry-pick revisions from the newest to the tip of the original branch.

So... say the remote branch is foo/bar and revisions are rev1 (oldest) and rev2 (newest).

What you do is:

```
git checkout rev1~1
git cherry-pick rev1..rev2~1
git cherry-pick rev2..foo/bar
```

When you reach this point, you could create a local branch on top of it or just push it into foo/bar if you want to replace it:

```
git push foo -f HEAD:bar
```